# Why the image is not displayed in my post?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this response from my local server(AdonisJs):

```
{"total":3,"perPage":5,"page":1,"lastPage":1,
    "data":[{"id":2,
             "category_id":20,
             "title":"Lion",
             "description":"Lion king",
             "img":{"id":1,"filename":"DPp6sNmHqM6oCnBBPyG8wJIW3Z0lRWon.jpeg",
             "original":"Lion.jpg","size":28992,"type":"image/jpeg"}}
]}
```

the local server folder is on my desktop near to the project folder. Before I added a few posts earlier, using method POST to the same local server in component `AddPost`

This is image. I need display post which contains: category_id, title, description and image

### But now display only category_id, title, description. And the image itself is not displayed.

Why can this happen?

## DisplayPost.js:

```
export default (props) => {
 return (
   <div>
     {props.dataAttribute.map(item => (
        <div>
          <div>Title:{item.title}</div>
          <div>Id:{item.category_id}</div>
          <div>Description:{item.description}</div>
          <div>{item.img.filename}</div>    // <-- THIS IS IMAGE
        </div>
      ))}
 </div>
 );
}
```

## Post.js:

```
const Post = () => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState({
        listImage: [],
    });

 useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(); 
  }, []);
    
    async function fetchData() {
        const data = await apiImage(`${imageRoute}`, {
          method: 'GET',
         });
          setValue(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            listImage: data.data,
         }));
    }

  return (
      <div>
        <DisplayPost dataAttribute={value.listImage} />
        <AddPost />
      </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is that a local asset or is it to be fetched from somewhere? You'll need an entire URL likely to set an image source attribute. What you have will just display the filename as text.

Comment: @Drew Reese the local server folder is on my desktop near to the project folder. Before I added a few posts earlier, using method POST to the same local server

Comment: I won't duplicate existing answer, but it'll be something like `<img src={\`${BASE_URL}/${item.img.fileName}\`} />` where BASE_URL is path to assets on the local server.

Comment: @Drew Reese existing answer didn't help. The image is also not displayed. The reason is something else.

Comment: It's technically correct but you need to heed the "*you need to provide the correct path to the image source though*" part. If you can figure out what the path is to the server where the file exists and use it and it's still not working please update question with these details.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add it to **src** props of html **img** tag:

```html
<div><img src={item.img.fileName}/></div>
```

kind of like that,
you need to provide the correct path to the image source though,

good luck

Comment: It didn't help. The image is also not displayed

Comment: please check again that the img url is correct, you can use the browser console also to check if there is any error on file not found condition

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

go check that url, that can help also